# Plotting regions in map using rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I was wondering if anyone can help. I am trying to map regions in a map in R, by using rworldmap and countrycode. However it doesn't seem to support the "ISO 3166-1" for the regions.  I have 14 countries and 40 regions to plot. Is there another way around it please? I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: could you explain the question a little better? a code sample would help anybody that wants to answer this

Answer (score 0):

this works...

```
library(rworldmap)
data(countryExData)
mapByRegion(countryExData, nameDataColumn="CLIMATE", joinCode="ISO3", 
            nameJoinColumn="ISO3V10", regionType="Stern", FUN="mean")
```

where `countryExData` is the example dataset included in the `rworldmap` package, "ISO3V10" is passed to the `nameJoinColumn` argument which is the name of the column/vector in the `countryExData` data frame that contains iso3c codes (as in USA or DEU), and "ISO3" is the value passed to the `joinCode` argument signifying to the `mapByRegion` function that the codes are "ISO3" which seems to mean iso3c specifically.

Comment: Dear CJ Yetman, Thank you soon much! I will try it now:):) I will let you know how it works;)